# Testing Application Controller - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd

How should I test this method on my `ApplicationController`:

```rb
def success
  render nothing: true, status :ok
end
```

I've tried using `controller.call(:success)`, but it returns an error.
Any ideas ?

Additional Info:
I'm using `rspec`

Answer (score 0):

I would test it like this:

```
it 'responds with success' do
  expect(response).to be_success
end

it 'renders nothing' do
  expect(response).to render_template(nil)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I meant how do I actually make a call to this method ?

Comment: Is the `success` method an action that should be called or are you trying to unit test the `success` method?

Comment: the `success` method is merely a helper of sorts, it doesn't have a route to it. A Controller (such as `UserController`) would call it, so something like this: 

user.save ? success : bad_request